# Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of " this" must be of type EventTarget

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to build a form that automatically sends an E-mail with Next.js using the new App Router.

I began with, what I think is a very simple post request to the '/api' route:

```js
// Prices.js
async function sendMsg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({test: 'ok'}),
    });
    console.log(res);
}
```

And a very simple route handler:

```js
// route.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
console.log('the route file!!! start');

export async function POST(request) {

    console.log('api post resquest ----> ', request);
    return NextResponse.json({res: 'ok'});
}
```

But I keep getting a 500 internal server error:

```
- error Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "
this" must be of type EventTarget
```

The project is here:
https://github.com/Tezcatlipoca0000/tez-web

I thought maybe the issue was with file structure, so I already tried saving my api folder inside the [locale] folder but that didn't help.

I also tried with Server Actions enabled but I kept getting the same error.

Comment: It's working for me. What's your Node.js version?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar 
Many thanks! 
You were right! I was using node version 16.16
As soon as I updated to 18.17 the problem was solved!
Should you post the answer? Should I? or should I delete the post?

Comment: My pleasure! I posted an answer, edited the title of the question as well. This will most likely help others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because you are using an older Node version. Migrate to the latest [recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) one. You can use the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) package from `npm`:

```bash
npm install -g n
n stable
# If one of the commands does not pass, you may need to use sudo
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Or install it directly from the [website](https://nodejs.org/en/), or use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)...